# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: laravel, post, authentication, routes

I'm using laravel 5.4,
And I need to open an endpoint for 'createUser'.

"LoginController.php"

```
public function createUser(Request $request)
{
    $data=$request->only('email','name','position');
    $validate=Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'name' => 'required',
        'position' => 'required',
    ]);

    $exUser=User::where('email','=',$request['email'])->first();
    $nameUser=User::where('name','=',$request['name'])->first();

    if(empty($exUser))
    {
        if(empty($nameUser))
        {
            $user=new User();
            $user->name=$request['name'];
            $user->email=$request['email'];
            $user->position=$request['position'];
            $user->password=hash('sha512',$request['password']);
            $user->save();
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json(['Name Has Already Taken'],500);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['Email Has Already Taken'],500);
    }
}
```

"RegisterController.php"

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'position' => $data['position'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);
}
```

"api.php"

```
<?php

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

     Route::get('users',['as' => 'user', 'uses' 
     =>'Auth\LoginController@getUsers']);

    Route::post('users', ['as' => 'createUser', 'uses' => 
    'Auth\LoginController@createUser']);
```

"User.php"

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'position' ,'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

"postman details"
[image]

The get "users" endpoint is working!
But when Im trying to call the "post" request using postman,It shows the error

"Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1374 and defined"

Any suggestions!

Comment: I think you need to share User model.

Comment: And postman details also ?

Comment: Added User model and the postman detail.Please check!

Comment: First why do you use `logincontroller` as `registercontroller`? Then why do you not use `User::create([...])` in your `createUser` method?

Comment: I'm new to laravel actually!. When I write the endpoint as "Route::post('users', 'RegisterController@create');" , It will also gives the same error

Comment: @DmsMalithDisanayake and what would that error be?

Comment: @lagbox same error

Comment: how many different `LoginController`s do you have?

Comment: @lagbox only one and also have "RegisterController"

Comment: so why the routes pointing to 2 different controllers, `Auth\LoginController` != `LoginController`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161161/discussion-between-dms-malith-disanayake-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 0):

This setup is working for me. Can you post your entire stacktrace? I might be able to give more specific help with that.

api.php

```
Route::post('users', ['as' => 'createUser', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@createUser']);
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
{

}
```

LoginController.php

```
public function createUser(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'unique:users|email|required',
        'name'     => 'unique:users|required',
        'position' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request['name'];
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->position = $request['position'];
    $user->password = hash('sha512', $request['password']);
    $user->save();

    return response('', 201);
}
```

tests\Feature\UserTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_can_create_a_user()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/users', [
            'email'    => 'user' . rand(0, 99999999) . '@gmail.com',
            'name'     => 'Billy ' . rand(0, 99999999) . ' Joel',
            'position' => 'Musician',
        ], ['Accept' => 'application/json']);

        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }
}
```

Comment: added the stacktrace. Is that the postman object will be set as a json array?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? I expected to see more lines. Yes, the unit test does the same thing as the postman test. The `post` method accepts 3 arguments: route, body, and headers.